# Tkinter button with the command if or else

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm sure that It's a very easy problem for you but huge for me.

I don't know how to create a command for my tkinter button with if and else.
In fact the idea is that when I input on the entry the word 'white' after pressing the button it must show me the label with 'RIGHT' but with this code the button always shows me WRONG...why?

This is the Code:

```
# coding=utf-8
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import time
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

schermata = Tk()
ment = StringVar()

schermata.geometry('750x500')
schermata.title('DANTE')

def comando():
    global input
    if ment=='white':
        time.sleep(1)
        risposta_giusta.pack()
        risposta_giusta.place(x=20, y=290)
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        risposta_sbagliata.pack()
        risposta_sbagliata.place(x=20,y=290)

def resize_image(event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image = photo)
    label.image = photo #avoid garbage collection

image = Image.open('dante.gif')
copy_of_image = image.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = Label(schermata, image = photo)
label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = YES)

font = ('Ubuntu',22)
font_2 = ('Ubuntu',12)
labelfont = ('Noto Serif CJK SC', 35, 'bold')
titolo = Label(schermata,text='DANTE',bg='#E5E3C6',fg='#BF000D')
titolo.config(font=labelfont)
titolo.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = YES)
titolo.place(x=20, y=20)

risposta_giusta = Label(schermata, text='RIGHT!!', font=font, bg='#E5E3C6',fg='#0F0000')
risposta_sbagliata = Label(schermata, text='WRONG', font=font, bg='#E5E3C6',fg='#0F0000')

domanda = Label(schermata, text="what is the color of Napoleone's horse?", font=font_2, bg='#E5E3C6',fg='red')
domanda.pack()
domanda.place(x=20, y=120)

input = Entry(schermata,textvariable=ment,bg='white',width=23,disabledbackground='black')
input.pack(ipady=3)
input.place(x=20, y=190)

bottone = Button(schermata,text='PARLA CON DANTE',command=comando,bg='#BF000D',fg='white')
bottone.pack()
bottone.place(x=20, y=245)

schermata.mainloop()
```

Comment: try `if ment.get()=='white':` under `comando()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `ment` is a tk `StringVar()` object.  In order to read the value of the variable you need to use the `.get()` method:

```
def comando():
    global input
    if ment.get()=='white':
        time.sleep(1)
        risposta_giusta.pack()
        risposta_giusta.place(x=20, y=290)
```

If you printed out `ment` You would notice it says `PY_VAR0` or similar (which is Tcl name of the string variable object), so it will never equal to `'white'`.